# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'

Tags: python, function, import, module, directory

I have a folder, called ABC that contains a file called `file_function.py`, i.e.

```
ABC
    file_function.py
```

I have a folder in ABC called folder_function that contains a file called `main_function.py`, i.e.

```
ABC
    folder_function
        main_function.py
```

In `main_function.py` I am calling a function defined in `file_function.py` called `xyz`. I am using the following code in `main_function.py`

```
from ABC.file_function import xyz
```

However, this results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'`.

I have tried solutions in other posts with no luck. What could possibly be the issue? Could it be a wrong environment setup? How can I go about debugging this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file function is not in folder function (main_function's parent), so it will give this error. A similar example is that your python program can't access your photos folder because they are completely different directories!

Try reorganizing the files. If it still doesn't work, than try this:

```
from ABC import file_function
from file_function import xyz
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Is there a way to call it without having to move file and folder locations?

Comment: try the second code way (the one in litterally black and blue)

Comment: That still didn't work. It's giving me the same error

Comment: It may be because of your version (it causes your error). Try upgrading to Python 3.10 or 3.11.

Comment: The same error for me, but files are located in the same folder (`__init.py__` is present). I can't use absolute path, but I need to use it

Answer (score 1):

In order for the files or folders of .py files to be callable with the . notation, they need to be modules. A module is defined by its `__init__.py` file at every root. The `__init__.py` can be empty, but it needs to exist, in this case in the ABC folder and in the folder_function folder.

**More Info**

[What is `__init__.py` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

[Thoughts on how you might want to structure your project and modules](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#modules).

Comment: __init__.py exists in both the ABC and folder_function folders. They are both empty .py files

Answer (score 0):

Go to the python download location and search for the python39 file. Inside it you will find pip39. In the address line, click with the mouse to show the full address and something will be close to the following
C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
Now open the magnifying glass at the bottom left of the screen and type in the search box sysdm.cpl. The system properties box will open, choose advance, scroll down to the bottom of the window and select environment variables
A window will open with two boxes, search in the lower box for the word PATH and double-click on it. A new window will appear. Select the path named PATH and type or paste over it the path shown above, of course, according to what is in the system in all cases, it will start with C :\ and end with \Script then click OK until All windows disappear
Now go back to Terminal and click Run. ModuleNotFoundError will disappear: No module named 'whatever the module name' and the script runs successfully