# ModuleNotFound Error On A Module I Have Already Installed

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I wanted to make an interactive program in the terminal so i downloaded the keyboard module by doing "python -m pip install keyboard". But when i tried to import the keyboard module into my program i got a ModuleNotFound error.

[The Error I Got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynTj3.png)

[I tried to install it again but it was already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsIb0.png)

I also tried installing pygame and it installed without a problem so i decided to test them in a program.

The code

```
import pygame
import keyboard
```

[The Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g13xL.png)

Comment: You might have different versions of python installed on your system. You installed keyboard module for Python 3.5 but you might be using another version of python on your code editor as an interpreter.

Comment: Posting errors as external links makes it harder for us to help.  All of the information we need should be directly in your question as plain text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72455673/python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-xyz